# Flutter - mock Future.wait in unit test

Tags: flutter, dart, future, flutter-test

I have a function that only return when it has made 4 sync calls to the `FlutterSecureStorage` package, something like this below. The aim is to not return until all of the Future from the `FlutterSecureStorage` method.

```
  @override
  Future<void> cacheAuthenticatedUserJWT(authenticateUserModel) async {
    return await Future.wait([
      flutterSecureStorage.write(
          key: CACHED_ACCESS_TOKEN, value: authenticateUserModel.accessToken),
      flutterSecureStorage.write(
          key: CACHED_REFRESH_TOKEN, value: authenticateUserModel.refreshToken),
      flutterSecureStorage.write(
          key: CACHED_EXPIRES_IN,
          value: authenticateUserModel.expiresIn.toString()),
      flutterSecureStorage.write(
          key: CACHED_TOKEN_TYPE, value: authenticateUserModel.tokenType),
    ]);
  }
```

Now when it come to testing I had something like this below:

```
test('should store of the tokens into flutter secure storage', () async {

      // Mock call of function
      dataSource.cacheAuthenticatedUserJWT(tAuthenticatedUserModel);

      // Verify all four calls have been made
      verify(secureStorage.write(
          key: CACHED_ACCESS_TOKEN,
          value: tAuthenticatedUserModel.accessToken));
      verify(secureStorage.write(
          key: CACHED_REFRESH_TOKEN,
          value: tAuthenticatedUserModel.refreshToken));
      verify(secureStorage.write(
          key: CACHED_EXPIRES_IN,
          value: tAuthenticatedUserModel.expiresIn.toString()));
      verify(secureStorage.write(
          key: CACHED_TOKEN_TYPE, value: tAuthenticatedUserModel.tokenType));
    });
```

This was working when I did not have the `flutterSecureStorage.write` as await, because they return nothing, however I then realised I don't what the next function to run until this is finished in the repository class, just to make sure the data is set when I make the HTTP call with associated Json Web Tokens. But now since they are async with the Future.wait, how can I mock this in the test? Is there a specific method with the `test_api` package?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

To wait a method to be called in the test,you can do:

```
 await untilCalled(myMockClass.myAsyncFunction());
 verify(myMockClass.myAsyncFunction());
```

note: the untilCalled method is coming from [mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) package

Comment: how can we test the differences between 2 implemented ways:

```await Future.wait([<List of Future>]);```

and

```await Future1;
await Future2;
...```?